# How to get process status using pid?

Tags: python

If I known a process's pid, how can I tell if the process is a zombie using Python ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a the `status` feature from [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process(the_pid_you_want)
if p.status() == psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE:
    ....
```

Comment: p.status() should be used (at least in python 3)

Answer (score 14):

here's a quick hack using `procfs` (assuming you're using Linux):

```
def procStatus(pid):
    for line in open("/proc/%d/status" % pid).readlines():
        if line.startswith("State:"):
            return line.split(":",1)[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
    return None
```

this function should return `'Z'` for zombies.