# PYTHON How to detect when a proccess has been ended

Tags: python, pid

Given a proccess name(PID is unkown), how can i detect when a proccess has been ended(Also how can i find out the PID given a proccess name)? Also, I'm doing this for windows explorer, so how would I track the proccess name as it changes as the user moves thorugh directories.

I'm using Python 2.7 and windows if that helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As Padraic Cunningham wrote here:
[Python: How to get PID by process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688936/python-how-to-get-pid-by-process-name)
In order to get pid from process-name:

```
from subprocess import check_output
def get_pid(name):
    return int(check_output(["pidof","-s",name]))
```

As Mat wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767792/5088142
In order to get status of a process using its pid your can use psutil https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

```
import psutil
print psutil.Process(pid).status
```

Edit: You can combine those two parts into the following code:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import psutil
def get_pid(name):
    return int(check_output(["pidof","-s",name]))
def get_status(name)
    pid = get_pid(name)
    print psutil.Process(pid).status
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but another question, how would i be able to constantly test for it ( i'm sorry im quite new, but i realise that checking for an update in an envrionment is important in porgramming) thank you once again :)

Comment: I've added a new function which combines the two parts of code. you can call the function get_status("process_name") and get the process status. (note that you'll need to install psutil)

Comment: thx, but would you happen to know a way to constantly check for this throughout my code, or is that not possible? thank you anyway :)

Comment: you can grab all pid with psutil
`import psutil
pids = [p for p in psutil.pids() if psutil.Process(p).name() == process_name]
print(pids)`

Comment: Please provide detailed scenario, so we'll be able to understand your needs. What do you want to check? How often?